# Make HTML input required dependent on whether shown or not

Tags: javascript, html

I have a section on a form where the user marks the status and if the user marks the status as 'Archived' it will show a div (using Javascript) and asks for the reason. How do I make this box required but only if it's shown? For example if the users selects another status which is not 'Archived' then the box won't be required.

**Choose Status**

```js
function admSelectCheck(nameSelect) {
  console.log(nameSelect);
  if (nameSelect) {
    admOptionValue = document.getElementById("admOption").value;
    if (admOptionValue == nameSelect.value) {
      document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "block";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="input-field col s12 m6">
  <select name="fdstatus" onchange="admSelectCheck(this);">
    <option value="<?= $cst['cst_status']; ?>" selected>
      <?= $cst['cst_status']; ?>
    </option>
    <option value="Prospect">Prospect</option>
    <option value="Appointment Booked">Appointment Booked</option>
    <option value="Test Drive Booked">Test Drive Booked</option>
    <option value="Proposal Offered">Proposal Offered</option>
    <option id="admOption" value="Archived">Archived</option>
    <option value="Deal Won">Deal Won</option>
    <option value="Deal Lost">Deal Lost</option>
  </select>
  <label>Customer Status</label>
</div>
<!-- If 'Archive' show -->
<div id="admDivCheck" style="display:none;" class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
    <input name="fdstatusArchiveR" id="fdstatusArchiveR" type="text" class="validate">
    <label for="fdstatusArchiveR">Reason for archive</label>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `admSelectCheck` function toggle the `required` on the input:

```
function admSelectCheck(nameSelect) {
  console.log(nameSelect);
  if (nameSelect) {
    admOptionValue = document.getElementById("admOption").value;
    if (admOptionValue == nameSelect.value) {
      document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById('fdstatusArchiveR').required = true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('fdstatusArchiveR').required = false;
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('fdstatusArchiveR').required = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not very DRY :)

Answer (score 1):

I added a class of hide to the div, an ID to the select and removed the inline event handler as recommended.

The script adheres to the DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself)

```js
document.getElementById("fdstatus").addEventListener("change", function() {
  const val = this.value; // select value
  const admOptionValue = document.getElementById("admOption").value; // option value of ID
  const show = val === admOptionValue; // boolean
  document.getElementById("admDivCheck").classList.toggle("hide", !show);
  document.getElementById("fdstatusArchiveR").required = show;
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
    <select name="fdstatus" id="fdstatus">
      <option value="" selected>Please select</option>
      <option value="Prospect">Prospect</option>
      <option value="Appointment Booked">Appointment Booked</option>
      <option value="Test Drive Booked">Test Drive Booked</option>
      <option value="Proposal Offered">Proposal Offered</option>
      <option id="admOption" value="Archived">Archived</option>
      <option value="Deal Won">Deal Won</option>
      <option value="Deal Lost">Deal Lost</option>
    </select>
    <label>Customer Status</label>
  </div>
  <!-- If 'Archive' show -->
  <div id="admDivCheck" class="row hide">
    <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
      <input name="fdstatusArchiveR" id="fdstatusArchiveR" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="fdstatusArchiveR">Reason for archive</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Test if required" />
</form>
```